# jQuery draggable weird behavior

Tags: jquery, html, css, draggable

I am using jQuery draggable to drag separate letters of the word "Hello" across the screen, but I've noticed annoying behavior.

If I drag the letter H to the right, anywhere near the letters E, L, L, or O, and then drop the letter, I can no longer "pick-up" the letter because it is now "trapped under" the other letters' h1 (I wrapped each letter in a separate h1).  The same goes for any other letter that is considered to be "below" the other (H being the "lowest" and O being the "highest").

It's difficult to explain so I'm including a fiddle to illustrate.  Drag the letter "H" right above the letter "E" (not on top of), let go, then try to pick it back up again and you won't be able to (until you move the "E" out of the way).  I put a border around each h1 so that you could see that it is the h1 that is somehow blocking me from picking up the letter.

The weird thing is that *this only happens in Chrome*.  I've tested it in IE10 on Win 7 and it's fine.

Any ideas on how to fix it?

**HTML:**

```
<body>
  <div id="name">
      <h1 id="h" ><a href=#>H</a></h1>
      <h1 id="e" ><a href=#>E</a></h1>
      <h1 id="l" ><a href=#>L</a></h1>
      <h1 id="l2" ><a href=#>L</a></h1>
      <h1 id="o" ><a href=#>O</a></h1>
  </div>
</body>
```

**CSS:**

```
        body {
        font-family: 'Sigmar One', cursive;
        font-size: 75px;
        color: white;
        text-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #000;

        background-color:blue;

        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
    }

    div {
        position:absolute; 
        height:100%; 
        width: 100%;
        display: table;
    }

    h1 {
        display: table-cell;
        vertical-align: middle;
        text-align:center;
        height: 1em;
        border: 1px solid black;
    }

    a {
        /*border: 1px solid black;*/
        display: inline-block;
        line-height: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    a:visited, a:hover, a:active {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: white;
    }

    a:link {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: white;
        text-shadow: 3px -3px 0px black;
    }

    a:hover {
        text-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #000;
        color: white;
    }
```

**jQuery:**

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#h, #e, #l, #l2, #o").draggable({ handle: "a" });
    });
```

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/8Huu7/36/

Comment: Why do you have to make the `h1` so large? Can't you make the `h1` as large as the letter so you avoid this problem? You can use `margin` for spacing instead.

Comment: I'm doing display: table-cell and vertical-align: middle, which is why they appear so big.  I'm up for other options if I can center the text in the middle of the page.

Comment: You say it works in IE10, however it's having the same issue, only reversed. Since you dropped x letter over y letter, you can only drag x letter. One of the two have to be on top, they can't exist on the same z-index. If you're hovering over both H and E, which one should be the one that you can drag?

Comment: @KevinB Not in my version.  I can drag both letters no matter what in IE10.

Comment: It also works for me in IE10.

Comment: Looks like expected behaviour to me. All elements have the same position and z-index. Thus the natural index is applied, where later elements are over their siblings.

Comment: @nietonfir Yes, but in IE10 as soon as the letter `H`, which is over letter `E`, ends you can drag the letter `E` from behind, even though the `h1` still overlays it.

Comment: @Cristy That works in Chrome as well. The problem OP describes is that he wants to repick `H`. And that doesn't work because of the implicit z-index. If it works in IE…well IE should be well known in the meantime for its quirks and bugs, don't you think? ;-)

Comment: @nietonfir "One man's bug is another man's feature"

Comment: @Keven It's definitely a bug, because you don't pick/hover over the letter, you pick the box (which has the letter as content). And if a box overlaps another box, you shouldn't be able to pick the lower box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@EveryoneWhoSaidItCouldn'tBeDone

I found a solution, and honestly, it was a simple change.  I can't believe I didn't think of it before (and wonder why no one else suggested it...).

Basically, I assign the IDs to the `<a>` tag instead of the `<h1>` tag.  And because the `<a>` tag is the draggable element now, there is no need for the `a` handle anymore in the jQuery.

(Although, I'm not sure if assigning an ID to a link element is kosher or not... never done it...)

That's it!

**NEW HTML:**

```
<body>
  <div id="name">
    <h1><a id="h" href=#>H</a></h1>
    <h1><a id="e" href=#>E</a></h1>
    <h1><a id="l" href=#>L</a></h1>
    <h1><a id="l2" href=#>L</a></h1>
    <h1><a id="o" href=#>O</a></h1>
  </div>
</body>
```

**NEW JQUERY:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#h, #e, #l, #l2, #o").draggable();
});
```

**NEW FIDDLE:** http://jsfiddle.net/8Huu7/45/

Comment: Why not just give all the links the same class and assign the event handler to the class...[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/warlock5658/8Huu7/46/)

Comment: @War10ck  Good point.  I guess I just assumed that by assigning the same class, the entire word would move together, rather than each individual letter.  So I never tried...

Answer (score 0):

Use the `z-index` property.
Here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#h, #e, #l, #l2, #o").draggable({ 
            handle: "a",
            start: function(){
                $('#name h1').css('z-index', 99);
                $(this).css('z-index', 999);
            }
        });
    });
```

And here is the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/8Huu7/41/

Comment: Hey thanks.  I tried your fiddle and it showed the same behavior.

Comment: Yeah, but now if you put `H` over `E` you can't grab the `E`. That's not what he's asking for.

Comment: Exactly.  It's similar to `stack` which brings the most recent object dragged to the top.  But that's not what I want.

Comment: I updated the fiddle. When you tried, I accidently set `attr` insead of `css`. Click on the fiddle again.

Comment: @YuraSokolov I tried it before and after.  Unfortunately, the current one won't work because now I can't drag the "E".  One letter should not overlap the other.

Comment: What you are asking is not possible. Try to do it not on the computer - take letters from paper surrounded by big transparent something, and drag them on the table. If you can figure out how you can drag the letters on the table with a finger - do the same in code. Here you have layers. Or forgot about the big h1 cells.

Comment: @YuraSokolov If that's the case then why does it work in IE10?

Comment: @Keven Simply put: bc it's broken. Don't get me wrong, the possibility would definitely be awesome. But that's not how HTML currently works.

Comment: Oh my... @Keven, IE never was a good example. He doesn't implements the rules of HTML and CSS properly. IE even not a real browser :) So if it works in IE, it not means, that it should work. I already said to you - try it in real life, not in the internet. If you can make it work in a real life, than you can make it work via code.